# Prove or give reference for $\int \frac{1}{\sum _{k=1}^n x^{k-1} \binom{n-1}{k-1}} \, dx=\frac{(x+1)^{2-n}}{2-n}$

Tags: integration, reference-request, binomial-coefficients

Mathematica knows that:
$$\int \frac{1}{\sum _{k=1}^n x^{k-1} \binom{n-1}{k-1}} \, dx=\frac{(x+1)^{2-n}}{2-n}$$

I have never seen this in a Mathematical handbook before. To me this explains the essence of the integration of fractions with polynomials in the denominator.

> Could you point me to a book or a formula collection, or even give a proof if you find it worth the effort?

Comment: So RHS's derivative is $(x+1)^{1-n}$? so it suffices to prove the sum in denominator is $(x+1)^{n-1}$ -- simple Binomial law? Is that all the question?)

Comment: Yes, exactly. I see it now when you say it.

Comment: Use the binomial theorem in the denominator and the integral is quite trivial ...
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int (1+x)^{1-n} dx = \frac{(1+x)^{2-n}}{2-n}.
\end{eqnarray*}